# Issue with transferring site written on Angular 6 to AWS S3 with the use of AWS CloudFront

Tags: angular, nginx, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I ran into a problem when transferring site written on Angular 6 to AWS S3 with the use of AWS CloudFront. Indicators of Google PageSpeed Insights differ from the production site with usage of Nginx and AWS S3 + AWS CloudFront, although it is exactly the same site version.
Site on nginx:
[PageSpeed score of nginx site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq90v.png)

Site on AWS S3 + AWS CloudFront:
[PageSpeed score of AWS S3+AWS CloudFront](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBmcU.png)

I have set AWS S3 storage with public access, and activated Static website hosting.
In the “Access Control List” I gave access to “List objects” for “Public Access - Everyone”. Also, I added metadata Cache-Control max-age=31536000 for every file in AWS S3 as it is on the production site.
[Metadata of each file in AWS S3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUeHx.png)

After that, I set AWS CloudFront Distribution, in which I connected AWS S3 storage. In the behavior settings I switched on the parameters of Cached HTTP Methods for OPTIONS, Object Caching - Custom where I set Minimum TTL = 31535999, Maximum TTL = 31536000 і Default TTL = 31536000. Also, I switched on the parameter Compress Objects Automatically.
[Behavior settings of AWS CloudFront Distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8zCX.png)

Also, here is my config nginx for the production site:
[Nginx configuration of production](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoWeL.png)

Please help me find the problem, maybe I made a mistake while setting everything. I would be grateful for your advice on how to configure AWS S3 + AWS CloudFront.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use Pretender?

https://github.com/theideasaler/angular-prerender

this is a complete instruction on how to implement it

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/prerender-angular-and-deploy-it-as-a-static-website-on-aws-s3-to-make-it-42-times-faster-115fadcf8614

Comment: No, I didn't use Prerender, I will read about this, maybe it`s will help me to solve problem. Thank you!